# Interrupt Service Routine GPIO toggle not happening fast enough at Timer overflow Event

Tags: c, timer, stm32, interrupt

I trying to implement a gpio toggle function using the STM32GO uC which can run at max clock speed of 64Mhz. I'm using the timer 16 instance to count ticks and run the interrupt callback function every 8uS.
So every 8us the uC will run the following code
'''code'''

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  if (htim == &htim16)
  {
        HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM16_IRQn);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5);
        static int count = 0;
        if(this_bit == 96)     //check if array is over
        {
            this_bit = 0;
            count = 0;
        }
        ++count;
        if(CARD_ID[this_bit])    //check if the bit to me modulated is 1
        {
         if(!(count % 5))
          {
           HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6);
          }
         if (!(count % 50))
          {
           this_bit = this_bit + 1;
           count= 0;
          }
        }
        else
        {
         if(!(count % 4))
          {
           HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6);
          }
         if (!(count % 50))
          {
            this_bit= this_bit + 1;
            count= 0;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

'''code'''

If I run this callback function without all of the logic and just a simple gpio toggle, I get the proper 8us toggle waveform on the oscilloscope.

But as soon as include this above mention logic the gpio toggle period increases to a maximum of 16uS.
This tells me the delay has to do with the excess code lines present in the ISR.
Is there a way to optimize this function so that i get the desired gpio toggle at 8uS with all this logic still in place?

The logic is to implement a FSK modulation on a carrier wave of 125khz, hence the frequency of gpio toggle needs to change for a binary '1' and the binary '0'.
The CARD_ID array just holds the sequence of the binary data which is used to modulate the carrier.

Thanks

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations ? There isn't much code here, definitely not more than the 500 cycles you need. However, you might want to ditch the HAL for this. You interrupt function isn't actually the interrupt vector. First it goes through the HAL dispatcher, which is out of your control. Coding this one manually without the HAL could save cycles.

Comment: Also, you don't need `HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ`. Your interrupt is already enabled. If not you wouldn't enter this interrupt.

Comment: Hey ElderBug, I'm a bit of a newbie to this stuff. How do compile with optimizations. Regarding the HAL, i kind of knew the HAL function is more of a higher level function call. Any pointers where i would find the low level ISR? Also to start the timer i should not worry about not using the HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT function right?

Comment: Did you look into the resulting assembly code? Commonly you can quickly spot suspects... -- Consult your compiler's documentation for optimization options.

Comment: Usually your IDE has a 'Debug' non optimized build and a 'Release' optimized build.

Comment: @ElderBug I tried the optimizations available in the IDE, still no effect. Also i put my logic in the low level IRQ handler for timer 16 still no effect. What else can be tried?

Comment: Another thing i wanted to mention is that if i change the timer interrupt to trigger at 20uS instead of the 8uS i want, it works fine with the above mentioned ISR code. I get the gpio toggle at 20uS.

Comment: Try not using the HAL for GPIO, and directly manipulate GPIO instead. Also, be careful with modulo (%). % 4 will be fast, but `% 50` and `% 5` will require a multiplication, which can be costly on a Cortex-M0. Use resetting counters, with ` == 50`  and ` == 5` and resetting to 0 instead.

Comment: Hey @Elderbug Thanks for the inputs, i was able to solve the timing issue after not using the modulus and implementing the logic as you mentioned. Appreciate the help.